# How to set up Javascript Soundcloud SDK for Web App

Tags: javascript, server, mamp, soundcloud

I'm trying to set up a SoundCloud SDK for a web application. 
I've managed to get a pop up asking for authorisation with the following code, on clicking connect however it doesn't respond.

Can anyone see any problems with this? 
Here is the Javascript.

```
SC.initialize({
           client_id: 'mygeneratedid',
           redirect_uri: 'file:///Users/simonmellows/Documents/Music%20Tech%20(Year%203)/Individual%20Project/Work/GUI%20Design.html'
        });

        // initiate auth popup
           SC.connect().then(function() {
           return SC.get('/me');
        }).then(function(me) {
           alert('Hello, ' + me.username);
           });
```

Here is my callback.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Connect with SoundCloud</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="window.setTimeout(window.opener.SC.connectCallback, 1)">
    <b style="text-align: center;">This popup should automatically close in a few seconds</b>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm running the file on my computer, it's not being hosted anywhere else. Does it need to be locally hosted? Or even on a remote server in order to work?
Any advice would be much appreciated. The above code is just what I've found from the documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To start with the value you specify as the "redirect_uri" MUST match the value you enter as the ***Redirect URI for Authentication*** on your registered Apps page on soundcloud.com (this it the same place you can view you client id & client secret).

The redirect URI must be an address that soundcloud can resolve and access.